# Detecting squares in a chessboard OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I detected a chessboard using OpenCV in python using:

- Computing the edge of the image
- Computing the Hough transform
- Finding the local maxima of Hough transform
- Extracting the image lines

Then I used `findContours` and `drawContours` functions:

```
  im_gray = cv2.imread('redLines.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))  
  morphed = cv2.dilate(im_gray, kernel, iterations=1)
  (ret, thresh) = cv2.threshold(morphed, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
  contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  cv2.drawContours(thresh, contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), 3)
```

And it worked well, the last imshow looks something like this:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to detect each square in the grid and save its points in a unique index in a vector.

I know I can do it using the contours array. But when I print the length of the contours it keeps changing rapidly, from size 2 up to 112..

So I guess it's not recognizing the grids well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your original, unprocessed image.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html (ignore the calibration part)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An approach is to use [contour area filtering](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) + [shape approximation](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#contour-approximation). Since a square has 4 corners, we can assume a contour is a square if it has four vertices.

Detected squares in green

[image]

Isolated squares

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread("1.png")
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove noise with morph operations
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
invert = 255 - opening

# Find contours and find squares with contour area filtering + shape approximation
cnts = cv2.findContours(invert, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4 and area > 100 and area < 10000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

cv2.imshow("original", original)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Other selection criteria can be "contour length over median contour length" in range [4/5, 6/5] and "area over median area" in range [(4/5)², (6/5)²] or similar.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yup that would be a great dynamic approach especially if the input image dimensions change